# prove unique solution for nonhomogeneous PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, singular-solution

I'm trying to prove a unique solution for this PDE

\begin{align}
u_{tt} (x,t)+(d+c) u_{xt} (x,t)+cdu_{xx} (x,t) &= F(x,t), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0 \\
u(x,0) &= f(x) \\
u_t(x,0) &= g(x)
\end{align}

I know the solution is

$$u(x, t) = \frac{cf(x - dt) - df(x - ct)}{c-d} -\frac{1}{cd}\int_{x-ct}^{x-dt}g(s)ds + \frac{1}{c-d}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x-d(t-\tau)}F(s,\tau)dsd\tau$$

What I'm thinking is to assume that $v(x,t)$ is also a solution, and some how plug in $w(x,t)=u(x,t)-v(x,t)$. Because I know that the homogeneous equation

$$u_{tt} (x,t)+(d+c) u_{xt} (x,t)+cdu_{xx} (x,t)=0$$

(already proved), I can say that

$$w_{tt} (x,t)+(d+c) w_{xt} (x,t)+cdw_{xx} (x,t)=0$$

is the unique solution for the homogeneous problem, and therefore $u(x,t)=v(x,t)$.

If I'm correct, what is the formal way to write that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying in the last paragraph. You just do as you did and consider the difference of two solutions, $w = u - v$, and look at the resultant PDE and data. You should find $w$ satisfies \begin{align} w_{tt} + (d+c)w_{xt} + cdw_{xx} &= 0 \\ w(x,0) &= 0 \\ w_{t}(x,0) &= 0 \end{align} What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you.